# Need to get description of a different column in my SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The table I'm working with has 8 different columns, I'm working with three called course_no, prerequisite, and description. the prerequisite shows what is needed to get into the course_no and the description currently shows the course_no description. I however need to get the description of the prerequisite while still showing the course_no. I am unsure of how to do this. I've looked up inner joins but they don't seem to be what im looking for. This is the sql statement just need to help figuring out how to show the description for the prerequisite column rather than course_no column.

```
SELECT course_no, prerequisite, description
FROM course
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `join` *is* what you are looking for.  Perhaps:

```
select c.*, p.description as prerequisite_description
from course c left join
     course p
     on c.prerequisite = p.course_no;
```

Comment: That would make more sense

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, changed it around and it worked fantastically! Thanks going to look at it and mess around with it so I understand it more. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

That would make more sense, the left join will course records even where there is no linked prerequisite, this will also show the course record multiple times if there is more than one matching record

```
SELECT c.course_no, c.description, NVL(p.description, '') as prerequisite_description
FROM course c 
    LEFT JOIN course p ON c.prerequisite = p.course_no;
```

If you only want 1 result row for each course, you could group concat the prerequisite descriptions

```
SELECT c.course_no, c.description, NVL(LISTAGG(p.description, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.course_no), '') as prerequisite_description
FROM course c 
    LEFT JOIN course p ON c.prerequisite = p.course_no
GROUP BY c.course_no, c.description;
```